# How to check the component based on particular schema

Tags: gui-extensions

We have the below code

```
var itemType = $models.getItemType(selection.getItem(0));
if itemType == $const.ItemType.COMPONENT
```

I want to check which schema is used for this component, based on this I want to enable user defined button in the ICM ribbon.

Please share the code how to check the component based on particular schema in JavaScript.

Comment: You question title and description is confusing, in title it says. "component based on schema", & in description it says. "which schema is used for this component", Please clean your question

Answer (score 4):

You may want to refer the below code to retrieve items filtered on the basis of a Schema TCM URI in Anguilla Framework:

```
$item = $models.getItem(id); 
$criteria = new Tridion.ContentManager.ListFilter();
$criteria.conditions.ItemTypes = 16;                //Get all items of type Component
$criteria.conditions.BasedOnSchema = "tcm:1-100-8"; // TCM URI of your Schema
$criteria.conditions.InclLocalCopies = true;       // Retrieve the Local Copies as well

// List of Components based on schema in Criteria
$list = $item.getListUsingItems($criteria, false, false);
```

I hope this helps you start.

Comment: i think he is asking to find the schema, but your answer suggest user should already know the schema id. i also think question is also confusing

Answer (score 2):

You can use following script to get schema Title: taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257535/how-to-get-the-schema-name-from-the-schema-object-in-tridion

```
var schemaObject = $models.getItem("tcm:8-32597").getSchema();
var schemaTitle;
function loaded()
{
    schemaTitle = schemaObject.getTitle();
}
$evt.addEventHandler(schemaObject, "load", loaded);
schemaObject.load(true);
```